# PhoneGap relative protocol issues

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have some Javascript for an API (SoundCloud) which I load into my PhoneGap app remotely and there are obvious issues with any asset that uses a relative protocol as PhoneGap will be using `file://`

So for any assets pointing to a relative protocol such as **`//foo.bar/api.js`** the PhoneGap app will try to fetch **`file://foo.bar/api.js`** which of course does not exist.

I do not have access to edit the API related assets. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @can u able to share code ? how you loading that sound cloud js files into your document ?

Comment: @amorbytes it's not a SoundCloud specific issue. I updated my question which might make it more readable.

Comment: can't you use `http://foo.bar/api.js` ?

Comment: @amorbytes there is an SDK which is hosted on a server - which then calls in another script using a //foo.bar/ type URL.

Comment: you MIGHT be able to simply include a <base> tag in the head, pointing an http location so that relative paths use http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just download the sdk, edit it (as in add the protocol) and just deliver it with your App.

As far as I know you can't just change the location.protocol property to make that work so everything else will be quite hacky so you should really stick to the first solution.

However, you could just get all "script" tags, iterate over them and check the src. If the src starts with an "//" you just create a new script node with the `"http://" + element.src` to load it properly. You'd most likely need to run that with a little timeout which slows down the whole App quite a bit and if a coworker of mine would do something like that I'd probably hit him but you know, it would work ;)

- Ben

Comment: Nice :) It has its own problems.
1. It will increase app size
2. We wont get latest updates
3. We need to change every time when SDK changed

Is there any way that we can check in network calls and if its starts with "//" we can append http or https.